Android emulator got stuck in unknown state and doesn't start
the place where emulator stuck I am starting andoid emulator for pixel fold and it look like this
I am trying to run my flutter project in emulator and it stuck in this state , also  when i run inside of android studio it stuck in this state too, I cannot find solution

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
